# What is $\cfrac 1n$ in this expression?

Tags: soft-question, notation, average

> I bought a T-shirt at Kenendy Space Center a while back that had this expression on it:
>
> ### $$
> B > \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
> $$

And below it is captioned "*Be greater than average.*"
I can see the "Be greater than" and the "average" in the expression, but I do not understand what the $\cfrac 1n$ is for.

> So, what is the purpose of $\cfrac 1n$ in the expression above?

(Sorry, I have absolutely no idea how to tag this)

Comment: Funny question :)

Comment: The term $\dfrac 1n$ is part of the average. If we wanted to find the average of two numbers $a$ and $b$, the average would be $\dfrac{a + b}{2} = \dfrac 12(a + b)$. The denominator is equal to the amount of variables we have. In this case, we have *two* variables $a$ and $b$, so we add them together and divide it by *two*. This means that the average of $a, b$ and $c$ is equal to $\dfrac{a + b + c}{3} = \dfrac 13(a + b + c)$. The average is also known as the *arithmetic mean*, and the right hand side of the inequality is just notation for the average of $n$ *given variables* denoted as $x_i$.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ is read as *the sum that goes from $x_1$ to $x_n$*. In other words, it is *the sum that takes the values of $x_i$ from $i = 1$ to $i = n$*. We can now write this as $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1 + x_2 +\cdots + x_n$$ and now to find the average of these $n$ different variables, we divide by the total of how many there are, which is $n$. This is the same as multiplying the entire sum by $\dfrac 1n$ which makes the right hand side of the inequality define the average of $n$ variables. Now it is clear that the symbols $$B>\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ means *be greater than the average*.

Comment: I mean the *Be* greater than average is really "readable" in the formula.  Nice one.

Comment: @ElfHog Well that’s why the formula is selling on a T-shirt haha.

Comment: @user477343 thanks, that comment actually answered my question. I must be blind not to see that the "sum" part didn't actually contain anything to divide it by the number of variables, which is where, of course, the 1/n comes in.

Comment: If you want me to write that as an answer, I will. I like to write answers as comments though because it’s about answering, not earning reputation (unless the current answers are misleading) :)

Comment: @user477343 that would be good, it goes into the most depth about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term $\dfrac 1n$ is part of the average. If we want to find the average of two numbers $a$ and $b$, the average would be $\dfrac{a + b}{2} = \dfrac 12(a + b)$. The denominator is equal to the amount of variables we have. In this case, we have *two* variables $a$ and $b$, so we add them together and divide it by *two*. This means that the average of $a, b$ and $c$ is equal to $\dfrac{a + b + c}{3} = \dfrac 13(a + b + c)$. The average is also known as the *arithmetic mean*, and the right hand side of the inequality is just notation for the average of $n$ *given variables* denoted as $x_i$.

---

$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ is read as *the sum that goes from $x_1$ to $x_n$*. In other words, it is *the sum that takes the values of $x_i$ from $i = 1$ to $i = n$*. We can now write this as $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = x_1 + x_2 +\cdots + x_n$$ and now to find the average of these $n$ different variables, we divide by the total of how many there are, which is $n$. This is the same as multiplying the entire sum by $\dfrac 1n$ which makes the right hand side of the inequality define the average of $n$ variables. Now it is clear that the symbols $$B > \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$ means *be greater than the average*.

Answer (score 10):

It's because the (arithmetic) mean (that is, the average) of the numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is$$\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}n=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i.$$

Answer (score 4):

The average (arithmetic mean) is the total of all entries over the number of them.

Answer (score 4):

That formula literally means

### BE(B) GREATER($>$) THAN THE AVERAGE($\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=i}^{n} x_i$)

Which mathematically is written as $$\large{B>\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=i}^{n} x_i}$$

### So the sum divided by $n$ represent the average here